# get array of duplicate item in list JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, arraylist

I have a list of objects and I want to separate them based on a field(age) and categorize them from small to large.

```
var data = [
  {
    name: "Mike",
    age: 10
  },
  {
    name: "Matt"
    age: 10
  },
  {
    name: "Nancy",
    age: 15
  },
  {
    name: "Adam",
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: "Jenny",
    age: 22
  },
 
];
```

The result should be something like this

```
[
[{name:"Mike",age: 10},{name: "Matt"age: 10}],
[{name: "Nancy",age: 15}],
[{name: "Adam", age: 22},{name: "Jenny",age: 22}]
 ]
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to approach a problem like this. One way is to use the .reduce() method to group the data by age.

```
var groupedData = data.reduce(function (result, currentValue) {
  if (!result[currentValue.age]) {
    result[currentValue.age] = [];
  }
  result[currentValue.age].push(currentValue);
  return result;
}, {});
```

The function is called for each element in the array, accumulating the results in the result variable. If the age is one we haven't encountered before, we create an empty array and add the value to it.

The initial value of the object groupedData is {}. If you console.log it, you will see:

```
{10: Array(2), 15: Array(1), 22: Array(2)}.
```

if you want groupedData to be an array you can use Object.values(). It will transform the object of arrays into an array of arrays.

```
groupedData = Object.values(groupedData);
```

Answer (score 1):

The function groupByAge is gonna do exactly what you need.

```
var data = [
  {
    name: "Mike",
    age: 10
  },
  {
    name: "Matt",
    age: 10
  },
  {
    name: "Adam",
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: "Nancy",
    age: 15
  },
  {
    name: "Jenny",
    age: 22
  },
];

function groupByAge(data) {
    
  const sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.age > b.age) return 1;
    if (a.age < b.age) return -1;
    return 0;
  });
  
  const returnData = [];
  
  sortedData.forEach((item) => {
    const foundedArray = returnData.find((elem) => elem.find((elemB) => elemB.age === item.age));
    if (foundedArray) {
        foundedArray.push(item);
    } else {
        returnData.push([item]);
    }
  });
  
  return returnData;
}

console.log(groupByAge(data));
```